# Stop Grails Controller from showing add option

Tags: grails

I am trying to use Grails to host a simple (personal) website, and was looking for a way to disable(or password protect them) the controller from showing the add and edit buttons for a Domain Object.

My Controller looks like this:

```
class DownloadsController {
    static scaffold = Download
}
```

My Domain Class looks like this:

```
class Download {

    static mapping = {
    }

    static constraints = {
        link(url: true)
    }

    String name
    String link

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the buttons are really the responsibility of the view, so you can edit the corresponding gsp. Are you using the scaffolding files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Spring security plugin, you can secure the urls for `edit` and `add` (and the `POST` urls) in the controller. See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html

If you are not using Spring Security, you may want to consider it as it seems to fit your requirements well. There are also convenient tags for use in your views (see http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty solution, you can override the edit/add scaffolded actions in your controller, like so:

```
class DownloadsController {
   static scaffold = Download

   //override scaffolded edit
   def edit() {
      redirect(action: "list")
   }

   //override scaffolded add
   def add() {
      redirect(action: "list")
   }
}
```

If you require a more sophisticated solution, have a look at the [spring security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)